# I am having a difficulty with first time react-native run-android. The Error looks like this following

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
     A problem occurred

> configuring project ':app'.
>         Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>           javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:

1. Make sure that java is installed on your system. Or install using linux command:

   `$sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. Set JAVA_HOME environment variable. 
   For linux

   `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"`

   to /etc/environment file new line.
3. Make sure Android/Sdk is included in your home directory.(i.e. Assuming you have installed android-studio).
4. Export ANDROID_HOME in `~/.bashrc` file.

   `export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
   export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
   export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
   source /etc/environment`

Last tip: if you get watchman error everytime you close(ctrl+c) and open the JS server. run the following command.

`echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman shutdown-server`

Answer (score 8):

If anyone else having the same problem with the above fix not working - then try installing JDK 1.8 instead of JDK 1.9 and set the JAVA_HOME environment variables. This fixed it for me.

Comment: This was my problem, and this fixed it. I will upvote this and the below answer AND the question in 15 hours when I am allowed to vote again :)

Comment: settings JDK 1.8 instead of 1.9 fixed my problem too

Comment: I did this and I still get the error. Using
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"

Answer (score 3):

**WINDOWS INSTRUCTIONS:** To update your *JAVA_HOME* Environment Variable:

1. press the Windows Key on your keyboard,
2. type "view advanced",
3. click on `View Advanced System Settings`,
4. click Environment Variables,
5. select *JAVA_HOME*,
6. click Edit,
7. click Browse Directory,
8. click This PC,
9. click C:\,
10. click Program Files,
11. click Java,
12. finally, select *jdk1.8.0_###* (actual build # may vary)

`missing JDK 1.8.0?` - Google "download Java JDK" and download it from oracle.com

Cleanup Phase: Press OK, OK, OK, OK

**RESTART THE COMMAND PROMPT** (if you encounter any issue now, try running Command Prompt as Administrator => right click, run as admin)

Now, try again (in the correct folder):

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: This actually don't work because, I do have the path set to the JDK. In my case it is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2. I have done a little research and it seems that most people are down grading to JDK8 to get it working. Just thought Id throw that out there.

Comment: Get JDK8 Here-->[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)